# Get some point location using the degrees based on the main point

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

Is there any way to get the P2's location (x, y) knowing the P1's location (30, 30) and the degrees between them?

**Edit**

Yes, I know the center location, and the P1 will be always above it.
The angle can be from 0º to 360º.

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you also know the center?

Comment: not without knowing the center

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I know the center X and Y.

Comment: @mbeckish I know the center of the circle's location...

Comment: This is more complicated than it looks.

Comment: What about http://i.stack.imgur.com/Shjxf.png?

Comment: Can the angle be 293 degrees?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, the angle can be from 0º to 360º. Take a look in the edit. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually just trying to find a point on a circle, given it's angle (from the top rather than the right side) and the radius of the circle.

```
X = center.X + r * cos(90 - angle)  
Y = center.Y + r * sin(90 - angle)
```

You may need to convert to radians.

Comment: Assuming that `r` is what?

Comment: @Alberto `r` can be easily calculated man. You have a line with two points a1,a2 and b1,b2. Distance between them is `sqrt(((b1-a1)^2) + ((b2-a2)^2))`

Comment: @noMAD, The main question isn't about how calculate `r`. The question is: what is it, based on the circle?

Comment: @Alberto: Well, if you use the formule above you need `r`. And you can get `r` this way. This solves your problem, right?

Comment: @Alberto: `r` is the radius of the circle.  In your case, it's just `P1.X - Center.X`.

Answer (score 2):

```
assume : 0<a:angle<90 ,c(x,y):center ,r:radius:distance between c & p1
```

b=arc(cos((xp1-xcenter)/r)))

> xp2 =  xcenter  +  r * (cos(b-a))  ,
>   yp2 =  ycenter  +  r * (sin(b-a))

if b=90 and xp1,yp1=30 :

> xp2  = r * cos(90-a) +  30 = r * sin(a)  + 30
>
> yp2 = 30 -   r * sin(90-a) = 30 -  r * cos(a)

Comment: Yes, Amin, I read your question. I'm trying another solution, but soon I'll try yours! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you know the diameter (or radius) of the circle (or, equivalently, the location of its center).

If you do, then you can work backward to the center of the circle, then use sin() and cos() to find the location of P2 (there are also other ways, of course -- that's just one obvious possibility).

Comment: The radius of the circle isn't enough - you need the location of the center.

Comment: Don't you think that with the radius I can get the location of the center of the circle decreasing the P1.y with radius?

Comment: @mbeckish: Maybe I was reading too much into his diagram, but I was assuming that P1 was at some known angle on the circle. But you're right: if P1 is at an unknown angle on the circle, then you need the location of the center to do much.

Comment: @Alberto: Only if P1 is guaranteed to be directly above the center.  Is it?

Comment: @SLaks Yes. P1 will be always above the center. :)

Comment: @Alberto - Please edit your question to include these facts.  That simplifies the math greatly.

Comment: @mbeckish Sorry, edited.

Comment: Can you post some equation?

Comment: @Alberto: I s'pose I could, but SLaks already has...

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate P1 around the center of the circle by the given angle.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  This is exactly identical to the problem of "Rotate P1 around the center of the circle by a given angle."

Comment: Doesn't seem like the original poster has that use-case. My impression is that using the given data, without modifying the points, how can you find P2? And you have the origin of the circle as well as the radius and degree between the points. If I'm wrong, then this is a great solution :)

Comment: Applying the rotation transform to P1's coordinates would give you P2's coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Its an isosceles triangle. In that triangle, you know two points, and all the angles. Just find the third point 
Here is the answer: [How to calculate coordinates of third point in a triangle (2D) knowing 2 points coordinates, all lenghts and all angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052720/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-third-point-in-a-triangle-2d-knowing-2-points)