# How to calculate third Coordinate of a triangle, knowing 2 coordinates and 1 angle?

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

I have a triangle ABC with 2 known coordinates A(5,5), B(6,3) and angle ACB = 30degrees and length AB = 2.24. With these values, how can i find the coordinates of third point C(x,y) ? Can anyone suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @Vignesh You can take this question to math.stackexchange

Comment: @John3136 If i get the answer i'll use it in my code to return the respective coordinates. Also these type questions are already existing in StackOverflow. Click this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052720/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-third-point-in-a-triangle-2d-knowing-2-points)  FYR.

Comment: @Vignesh How is your question not a duplicate of the one you linked to? Just bacuase someone else got one through almost 5 years ago doesn't mean it's right!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: The only problem with math.stackexchange.com is that they will give you a bunch of vectors and formulas you do not understand, lol.

Comment: Also, to answer this question, like Stuti said, you need more information, e.g. another distance or another angle.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a unique answer. Consider seg AB to be a chord in a circle. All the angles subtended in the major arc will be 30 degrees, if the central angle is 60. So any point on the major arc could be point C for you.

Comment: It's true for any other angle too. Draw a perpendicular to AB, intersecting anywhere between A and B. Taking a point on this line to be the third vertex, you can get any angle 180>x>0. Therefore there is a point on this line that gives the angle you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need more information.

For example, if you know the angle at B and the distance BC you could use something like [this code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115988/371917), although you will have to replace the distance with an input argument for BC.